# Compile error AssemblyInfo.vb

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am practicing MVC4 using the WebAPI Template in Visual Studio 2012, but when I try to compile the default project it gives me 12 errors in AssemblyInfo.vb:

Error   1   String constants must end with a double quote.  c:\users\taccongj\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\ActiveDirectoryAPI\ActiveDirectoryAPI\My Project\AssemblyInfo.vb    12  28  ActiveDirectoryAPI
Error   2   Syntax error.   c:\users\taccongj\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\ActiveDirectoryAPI\ActiveDirectoryAPI\My Project\AssemblyInfo.vb    13  4   ActiveDirectoryAPI
Error   3   Assembly or Module attribute statements must precede any declarations in a file.    c:\users\taccongj\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\ActiveDirectoryAPI\ActiveDirectoryAPI\My Project\AssemblyInfo.vb    14  1   ActiveDirectoryAPI
Error   4   Assembly or Module attribute statements must precede any declarations in a file.    c:\users\taccongj\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\ActiveDirectoryAPI\ActiveDirectoryAPI\My Project\AssemblyInfo.vb    15  1   ActiveDirectoryAPI
Error   5   String constants must end with a double quote.  c:\users\taccongj\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\ActiveDirectoryAPI\ActiveDirectoryAPI\My Project\AssemblyInfo.vb    15  30  ActiveDirectoryAPI
Error   6   Labels are not valid outside methods/multiline lambdas. c:\users\taccongj\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\ActiveDirectoryAPI\ActiveDirectoryAPI\My Project\AssemblyInfo.vb    16  5   ActiveDirectoryAPI
Error   7   Syntax error.   c:\users\taccongj\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\ActiveDirectoryAPI\ActiveDirectoryAPI\My Project\AssemblyInfo.vb    16  5   ActiveDirectoryAPI
Error   8   Assembly or Module attribute statements must precede any declarations in a file.    c:\users\taccongj\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\ActiveDirectoryAPI\ActiveDirectoryAPI\My Project\AssemblyInfo.vb    17  1   ActiveDirectoryAPI
Error   9   Assembly or Module attribute statements must precede any declarations in a file.    c:\users\taccongj\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\ActiveDirectoryAPI\ActiveDirectoryAPI\My Project\AssemblyInfo.vb    19  1   ActiveDirectoryAPI
Error   10  Assembly or Module attribute statements must precede any declarations in a file.    c:\users\taccongj\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\ActiveDirectoryAPI\ActiveDirectoryAPI\My Project\AssemblyInfo.vb    22  1   ActiveDirectoryAPI
Error   11  Assembly or Module attribute statements must precede any declarations in a file.    c:\users\taccongj\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\ActiveDirectoryAPI\ActiveDirectoryAPI\My Project\AssemblyInfo.vb    35  1   ActiveDirectoryAPI
Error   12  Assembly or Module attribute statements must precede any declarations in a file.    c:\users\taccongj\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\ActiveDirectoryAPI\ActiveDirectoryAPI\My Project\AssemblyInfo.vb    36  1   ActiveDirectoryAPI

Anybody have any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: show the code so we can see.

Comment: Show us the AssemblyInfo.vb :)